# Rails 3: Dynamically set after_filter in before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filter

I would like to define an `after_filter` to restore the changes of my `before_filter`, such that the changes made only affect that one action in my controller. Here's what I have so far:

```
before_filter :exclude_root_in_json
after_filter :restore_root_in_json

def exclude_root_in_json
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
end

def resotre_root_in_json
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

Is there any way I can do something like the following?

```
def exclude_root_in_json
  default = ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json
  ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
  self.class.after_filter do
    ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = default
  end
end
```

My end result is to end up with a `before_filter` call that automatically undoes the changes for that one particular action once that action is completed. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might be able to use an `around_filter`. Check out this page of the api docs:

http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html

Try it like so:

```
around_filter :exclude_root_in_json

private
  def exclude_root_in_json
    default = ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json
    ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
    yield
    ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = default
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, I had tried those, but my "after" filter was never getting called (using the syntax on that same page that starts with `around_filter Authorizer.new`). Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: That should be working, try the format I added above just to see.

Comment: Ahh, that syntax is working for me now. Also, I edited the question, as it's `ActiveRecord` not `ActiveSupport`, FYI. Thanks again!